# Crystal Viewer keep asking logon prompt C# Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, crystal-reports

I tried many solutions from internet, but they cant fix it.
I have code to load rpt file with C# asp.net. it successfully loaded, then logon prompt pop up, and i entered username and password correctly, but it just loading the same page and the pop up keep asked me for the username and password.
I'm using ODBC for the connection.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJC6m.png)

Here is my code:

```
public static void ReportLogin(ReportDocument crDoc, string Server, string Database, string UserID, string Password)
    {
        crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Server;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Database;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = UserID;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = Password;
        crDatabase = crDoc.Database;
        crTables = crDatabase.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
        {
            crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
        }
    }
```

If anybody have same issue and have the solution, please tell me.

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Jodi

Answer (score 1):

coba di comment bagian crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);

Comment: sudah saya coba. tapi dia terus muncul pop up logon promptnya. saya input  username sama passwordnya, loading sebentar langsung muncul logon prompt lagi